# jQuery Mobile listview descrption with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a listview with some long title which automatically  is hidden on small screen display and post fixed with ...

I am not sure if it is possible to make these long title of descriptions to scroll if whole title doesnt show up on the screen.

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVtVE/16/)

```
<div data-role="page" id="MessagesPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#HomePage" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>      
        <h1 id="ScheduleDayText">Messages</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" id="MessagesList" data-autodividers="false">
            <li date="2013-03-20"><a href="#">Event 1 With take every second Saturday of each month</a></li>
            <li date="2013-03-20"><a href="#">Event 2 With take every second Thrusday of each month</a></li>
            <li date="2013-03-19"><a href="#">Event 3</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can we make title to scroll to left or right on mouse hover so that user can read the title before they click on the link or button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I came out with a better idea, using CSS3 animation. On `vmouseover` a class `.marquee` will be added to `<a>` and animate its' text. After the animation is done, everything will be changed to normal.

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Jfpnc/)

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="MessagesPage">
 <div data-role="header"> <a href="#HomePage" data-icon="home" data-  direction="reverse">Home</a> 
     <h1 id="ScheduleDayText">Messages</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="MessagesList" data-autodividers="false">
        <li date="2013-03-20"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

        </li>
        <li date="2013-03-20"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet ullamcorper vehicula. Cras eros augue, mollis vitae aliquet auctor, porta.</a>

        </li>
        <li date="2013-03-19"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum et.</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS + Animation

```
.marquee {
 white-space: nowrap !important;
 overflow: visible !important;
 animation: right-left 5s ease;
 -moz-animation: right-left 5s ease;
 -webkit-animation: right-left 5s ease;
}

@-moz-keyframes right-left {
0% {
    -moz-transform:translateX(0);
}
50% {
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
 }
 100% {
    -moz-transform:translateX(-200%);
 }
}
/** Webkit Keyframes **/
 @-webkit-keyframes right-left {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-200%);
 }
}
```

JS

```
$("#MessagesList li").on('vmouseover', function (event) {
 var text = $(this).find('a').text();
 var textlength = $(this).find('a').text().length;
 var where = $(this).find('a');
 var root = $(this);
 if (textlength > 50) {
    where.addClass('marquee');
    where.css('text-overflow', '');
    //$("MessagesList").listview('refresh');
}
$("a").on('animationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('marquee');
    //$("MessagesList").listview('refresh');
    $(this).css('text-overflow', 'ellipsis');
 });
});
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Well, I found a way to add `<marquee>` to scroll. However, I didn't test it on Mobile. I hope this works for you.

```
$("#MessagesList a").on('vmouseover vmouseout', function (event) {
 var text = $(this).text();
 if (event.type == 'vmouseover') {
  $(this).html('<marquee behavior="slide" direction="left">' + text + '</marquee>');
 }
 if (event.type == 'vmouseout') {
  $(this).text(text);
  $(this).find('marquee').remove();
 }
});
```

Comment: This can be one solution but using marquee in this case has disadvantage as marquee in this case works for small heading also  & secondly it starts marquee from extreme right while i want marquee to start from left. Anyways i appreciate your help. I will see if i can use and slider effect with it as now i have idea from your approach. Thanks Again +1 from me..

Comment: it can be tuned, such as if text length exceeds 50 characters, it scrolls, otherwise no. @KnowledgeSeeker

Comment: @Omar: Exactly what i meant in my comment. I will accept your answer as this is what i had asked in my question.

Comment: Thank you @KnowledgeSeeker I'm working on some tweaks to have it work as you want :) Jazakallah khair bro..

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you wanted but as you hover over the list it'll show the full content

```
$("#MessagesList a").bind('hover',function(event){
 $("#MessagesList a").css('white-space', 'nowrap');
 $(this).css('white-space', 'normal');
 $("#MessagesList").listview("refresh");
});
```

This is a live fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/w6wSC/

Comment: To scroll not remove wrap and `ellipse` ;)

Comment: @Omar datz why I mentioned `exactly not what you wanted` in my answer :)