# scroll header text using jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on mobile version of a website & need to add a scrolling functionality when text is longer than certain pixels. I am trying to implement following logic into my project

[Source of scrolling example](http://jsfiddle.net/ranadeep/Ybq37/)

[I want to implement same in my example](http://jsfiddle.net/rZHMv/5/) so far i am not able to make it work my basic structure will remain same i only want to scroll text if screen is small to show complete title.

```
$("div.aaa h2").each(function(){    
  var m = $(this).width();
  var n = $(this).find("div.aaa h2").width();
  var o = m - n;
  var z = $(this).find("div.aaa h2");

    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        //alert ("title: " + m + " text: " + n + " diff: " + o);
        if (n > m) {
             z.animate({
             left: o                    
         }, 2000);
       }
    }).mouseleave(function(){
            z.animate({
            left: "0"
         }, 2000);    
    });        

});
```

I am open to any solution which is working & detects if complete title is visible or not then it should implement scrolling on for those elements which has long title not all.

Other approach i tried also failed as it scrolls all the elements not the one on which i do mouse hover

http://jsfiddle.net/yVtVE/21/

Comment: You could use the same method in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676121/jquery-mobile-listview-descrption-with-scrolling/15679055#15679055). It can be set to work based on screen width.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ctC97/

Answer (score 3):

Added extra parameter "elem" to animateTitle function, elem is defined when hover event done.
I removed `width:330px` css code from `.aaa` class. Added extra control for `.aaa` element's width (while hovering `.aaa` class element).

Here is your solution :   [jsfiddle.net/yVtVe/22/](http://jsfiddle.net/yVtVe/22/)

Comment: Your solution is exactly what i am looking for but my actual markup id slightly different than what is using in this one. I would appreciate if you can help me fix this one http://jsfiddle.net/yVtVE/24/, I tried to make it work which so far i am not able to as i am just a learner when it comes to jQuery. I would appreciate ur reply.